# how to terminate system() call in C

Tags: c, linux, shell

How to kill system() process (which is hung) within the same sourcecode is my question. An alternate to do this is sending SIGTERM or SIGKILL from another terminal/command line to that pid but former option is what I am looking for. Because we know system() call will block all signals until it completes/exits hence I can't find any solution to this.Below code will give you more clarity. Also let me specify that df ( bdf in hp-ux ) shell command is hanging (waiting for nfs/network resources) and hence I want to terminate it after 7 seconds.
To add, my code is serving the purpose of coming out in 7 seconds but process bdf is stuck somewhere in background getting itself parent id as init (1) .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/signal.h>

#define endl printf("\n")
pid_t child_pid;


void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    endl;
    printf(" Exiting after 7 seconds ");
    endl;
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);
    void sig_handler(int sig);    /// reestablishing signal
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid=fork();

    if(pid<0)
    {
        perror(" cannot create process/child");
        endl;
    }

    if(pid==0)
    {
        child_pid=getpid();
        printf(" Executing bdf command with process id %d",child_pid);
        endl;
        signal(SIGALRM,sig_handler);
        alarm(7);
        system("bdf");
    }
    if(pid>0)
    {
        sleep(7);
        exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you recursing into signal handler itself?

Comment: Why don't you indent your code properly?

Comment: @t0mm13b The code isn't recursing in the signal handler.  `void sig_handler(int sig);` is just a declaration - one that doesn't do anything and is somewhat nonsensical. What is wrong is the calling of `printf()` from within the handler - that's undefined behavior since `printf()` is not an async-signal-safe function.

Comment: @AndrewHenle look at the code as is shown, either its a messed up formatting, and yes, printf is not async nor thread nor signal safe also.

Comment: instead of being fuzzy about things for which I am not caring about right now please try to answer what I have asked in my question. printf I will remove from sig_handler that is of no concern here, I wanted to know how could system() process id can be caught/controlled.

Comment: OP: then what's `endl;` ? Sounds like a butchered up C++ code cruft got in there, heck, it would not compile either, so either post a correct [MCVE] . The answer was given below by Basile.

Comment: @t0mm13b What do you think the line `void sig_handler(int sig);` does?  The only actual calls made in the signal handler are three `printf()` calls, then one `signal()` call.  The signal handler doesn't do anything else - in fact, it's very presence causes the alarm signal to *not* cause the child process to exit.  The only reason the parent process ends after 7 seconds is because it sleeps for that much time.

Comment: @theartist33 You haven't solved your problem - `system()` creates a child process, as you know, but simply interposing *another* process in between does nothing for the child process that `system()` spawns.

Comment: @Andrew Henle by solving problem I meant that cos parent is coming out and child is lost in background so atleast I am getting shell prompt on unix machine else bdf hangs forever and you need to login to another terminal to do some other work ( Note : ctrl -C also dont work once bdf hangs )

Comment: Your comment that "this is demo code so pls dont stuck on usage of variables" is not a good sign.  Whereas I'm prepared to cut you slack on variable usage if the code you present is a *bona fide* [mcve], it appears instead to be merely a hacked-together approximation of what you think you want to do.

Comment: Could you clarify which operating system you're using? You tagged your question `Linux`, but `bdf` is an HP-UX command.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick   I am using HPUX , I have already mentioned it in my original question

Comment: 1) posted code is missing the headers for `fork()`, `sleep()`, `alarm()`, `getpid()`, 2) parameter `sig` not used in signal hander, suggest: `(void)sig;` as first line of code in the `sig_handler()` function.  3) the parameters for main() `argc` and `argv` not use suggest using signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: at this line: `child_pid=getpid();` the `pid` variable is still visible, suggest: `child_pid = pid;`

Comment: suggest read the man page for `signal()`, which will tell you to use another function like: `sigaction()`

Comment: this line: `void sig_handler(int sig); ` inside the `sig_hander()` function will be seen by the compiler as a prototype rather than a recursive call.  Strongly suggest removing that line.

Comment: three `if` statements should be rewritten as a `switch(pid)` statement.   the code block beginning with: `if(pid>0)` should perform a `wait()` or `waitpid()` call, NOT call `sleep(7)`;

Answer (score 6):

Don't control `system` and in your particular case don't even use it.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (it is freely available, also [here](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)!) then use the lower-level system calls like [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) (also perhaps [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) & [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) & [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), notably if `bdf` is a command giving some interesting output) etc... That ALP book has several chapters to explain you how to do that.

Remember that under the hoods [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) would just fork&exec the `/bin/sh` program with the `-c` option. You could do explicitly likewise (but you'll better implement any needed [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) in your program itself; apparently in your case you don't need that & you could fork then [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) the `"bdf"` program directly).

Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and notice that your program is wrong (has undefined behavior) since it is calling `printf` from inside a signal handler. This is forbidden (since `printf` is not an *async-signal-safe* function).

#### addenda

in your newly edited question, try to replace

```
if(pid==0) {
    child_pid=getpid();
    printf(" Executing bdf command with process id %d",child_pid);
    endl;
    signal(SIGALRM,sig_handler);
    alarm(7);
    system("bdf");
}
```

with

```
if(pid==0) {
    child_pid=getpid();
    printf(" Executing bdf command with process id %d\n",
           child_pid);
    fflush(NULL);
    signal(SIGALRM,sig_handler);
    alarm(7);
    if (execlp("bdf","bdf", NULL)) {
      perror("exec bdf");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Then use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (with `-f`) to understand what is going on.

But you need to **spend a few days reading good books** (such as [ALP](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)) **about Linux programming**. You cannot avoid the effort of understanding how processes work on Unix/Linux and POSIX systems.

Comment: even when I am using execv in child process it is blocking my alarm function and hangs forever ( because bdf hangs ). Although I can put an end to this waiting by calling shell command kill from parent ( through execv again ) for this child's id but  I don't want to do that ( for personal reason you can say ).

Comment: read my above comment pls

Comment: Did you take a few days to carefully read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ? We don't have time (or place, or incentive) to teach all the material you can find there (or in most POSIX programming books). And obviously an answer of more than a hundred pages won't fit here.

Comment: @theartist33 Can you edit your question to show the new code you wrote that uses fork and execv rather than system?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I posted new code . pls check

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can understand what you talking about. I was upto make use of execv or execlp but no good probably because shell commands through exec family is blocking alarm signal internally.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can understand what you talking about. I was upto make use of execv or execlp but no good probably because shell commands through exec family is blocking alarm signal internally.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch so since bdf hangs and so does endless waiting of exec hence alarm (SIGARLM) will never be delivered resulting no good. One option I thought of getting it done to kill this exec pid ( that would be calling id ) from another id (say parent context after sleeping parent for few seconds)

Answer (score 0):

@Mark : this is the new code

```
#define endl printf("\n")
pid_t child_pid;
int statloc;

void sig_handler(int sig)

{
endl;
printf(" Exiting after 7 seconds ");
endl;
signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);
}
int main()

{
pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
if(pid<0)
{
perror(" child error");
endl;
}

if(pid==0)
{
char * arg[]= {"bdf", NULL } ;
child_pid=getpid();
printf(" Executing bdf command with process id %d",child_pid);
endl;
signal(SIGALRM,sig_handler);
alarm(4);
execv("/usr/bin/bdf",arg);

}

if(pid>0)
{
waitpid(pid,&statloc,0);
exit(0);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use fork and exec to get the pid, store it.  Then you can kill it whenever you want.

Do not use system if you need the pid.

system should only be used on processes that will terminate naturally.

Consider system( "process &" )
this will allow the system to run in the background while allowing the parent to continue running in the current space.

Comment: point is I do not want to use shell command through exec from another process(say parent ) to kill child (through use of kill ). I am more likely looking for signal to kill that exec within (from that process itself ) or through use of somekind of timeout/alarm which i am finding difficult because alarm acts as suicide and sends SIGALRM which by default terminate process but not happening cos exec is blocking that signal until it succeds. Plus also I am not sure if it will work ever cos exec overwrites on calling process (although it inherits pending signals of calling process )